# Set a default admin ownership to files and folder in share file server Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-permissions, file-server

I have a File Server on a Windows Server 2012, with a single share-folder with all departments folders inside. The Domain\Administrator is the owner of the root shared folder. Sometimes when a regular user transfers or creates a new file or folder in this Share Folder this regular user takes ownership of this file or folder. I need to make all files and folders transferred or created inside the shared folder to be Administrator ownership by default.

Comment: The owner is the account that creates it.  There is no way a non-administrator can change the ownership to administrator.  Why do you think you need this anyway?  What is the 'real' problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: On the File Server every time that I need to assign a new user to one of the department folders, if new files or folders have been created under the ownership of a regular user, the administrator would not able to assign new security to these files or folders. A temporary workaround that I found is regaining ownership of the root folder and applying it to all sub-folder and files.